# Are there someone can explain me how to go from the first to the second? Thanks

Tags: mining-profitability

The first: BTC/day= 24 / (D * 2^32 / (H * 10^6) / 60 / 60) * C

The second: BTC/day=  (H*B/D) * 20.11626

In the first formula that I find in a discussion, I can't understand the mathematic form. In my opinion is not clear the sequences of the fraction and how I can pass from the first to the second.
Could be helpful a legend to describe what is the significate the numbers inside the formula.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add more information explaining where you got those equations from and what all the variables mean. For example, what are D, H, and B. The first equation has no B in it, so they're obviously not equivalent.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate because all the equations you mentioned are explained in the answers and comments of the question I linked.

Comment: Ok I understand.